# Sometimes don't have permission to create new folders on an NTFS partition in Evince

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, evince

My hard drive has an NTFS partition mounted under Ubuntu 12.04.

I use Evince as the default application to open PDF files downloaded under Firefox. 
I often save copies of PDF files opened in Evince to the NTFS partition, and before that, I would like to create new folders in the NTFS partition, for where the PDF files will be saved, by hitting "Save a Copy ..." and "Create Folder" under Evince.

Sometimes new folders in the NTFS partition could not be created using the above way in Evince, for the reason of "Error creating directory: Permission denied", and alternatively, I have to create new folders under Nautilus before I can save copies of PDF files into them under Evince. This is troublesome, because I can't create new folders and save PDF files both under Evince.

But the problem doesn't always happen, and sometimes I can be permitted to create new directories in the NTFS partition under Evince.

So I wonder why the problem happens and what I can do to solve the problem?

Comment: When the problem happens what is the output of `mount`?

Comment: `/dev/sda3 on /windows-d type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)`. I think the output of `mount` doesn't matter, because I can create new folders under Nautilus when the problem happens.

Comment: Can you create new directories using "mkdir" (e.g. `mkdir /windows-d/foo/`)?

Comment: Yes, I can. @samlam. The problem happens under Evince.

Comment: I get the sense that "permission denied" really means something else, such as "path too long".  One way to see what's going on is to use `strace` to run evince with a PDF file that consistently creates the problem in question, e.g. `strace evince '/windows-d/users/foo/bar/file with many spaces/something that makes the file really long/and longer/and so on/Here is the problem file.pdf' > strace.output 2>&1` Then read the strace.output file.

Comment: @samiam: it doesn't matter if "path too long" or short. Does `evince '/windows-d/users/foo/bar/file with many spaces/something that makes the file really long/and longer/and so on/Here is the problem file.pdf'` open the pdf file? My problem happens only when creating a new folder for saving a pdf under Evince.

Comment: So what happens when you try to use `mkdir` to create that folder?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12796/discussion-between-samiam-and-tim)

Comment: If you run evince under strace, it will run normally (albeit slowly).  Let me rephrase the question: What do you see in `strace.output` if you start evince with strace (`strace evince > strace.output 2>&1`) and and then select "Save a Copy ..." followed by "Create Folder" under the straced Evince (using a location with the problem)?

Comment: @samiam: Thanks! I followed your instructions, and here is the content of `strace.output`: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/strace.output

Comment: Here's the relevant call: mkdir("/windows-d/academic discipline/study objects/areas/formal systems/logic/generalize to when inference is uncertain/uncertainlize deductive logic/statistics/general/Ogunnaike/new", 0777) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied) so let's try `mkdir 'windows-d/academic discipline/study objects/areas/formal systems/logic/generalize to when inference is uncertain/uncertainlize deductive logic/statistics/general/Ogunnaike/new'` from the command line.

Comment: @samiam: `mkdir '/windows-d/academic discipline/study objects/areas/formal systems/logic/generalize to when inference is uncertain/uncertainlize deductive logic/statistics/general/Ogunnaike/new'` from the command line works, just as I can create the folder under Nautilus. But I hope to create the folder under Evince.

Comment: OK, remove the directory and make it again, but this time let's see the strace output.  e.g. `strace mkdir '/windows-d/academic discipline/study objects/areas/formal systems/logic/generalize to when inference is uncertain/uncertainlize deductive logic/statistics/general/Ogunnaike/new' > strace.mkdir.output 2>&1`

Comment: @samiam: Thanks! Output is here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/strace.mkdir.output

Comment: Are you running selinux per chance?  If so, look at the file `/var/log/audit/audit.log` to see if selinux is blocking evince.

Comment: @samiam How shall I find out if I am running selinux?

Comment: Is there selinux-related stuff in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`?  What are the contents of `/etc/selinux/config`?

Comment: @samiam: there do not exist `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and `/etc/selinux/config`, and I can't find `audit.log` file using `locate -i audit.log`. But `locate -i selinux` returns some results.

Comment: Some more tries: `ls -l $( which evince )` (to see if it is somehow SUID).  Then let's try `mkdir '/windows-d/academic discipline/study objects/areas/formal systems/logic/generalize to when inference is uncertain/uncertainlize deductive logic/statistics/general/Ogunnaike/newER'` to see if the bug is trying to make a given directory the first time.

Comment: @samiam: (1) I found a file `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-58/security/selinux/Kconfig`. Is its content helpful? it is here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/Kconfig. (2) `$ ls -l $( which evince )
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 427384 Jul 21  2013 /usr/bin/evince`. (3) `mkdir '/windows-d/academic discipline/study objects/areas/formal systems/logic/generalize to when inference is uncertain/uncertainlize deductive logic/statistics/general/Ogunnaike/newER'` works without bug.

Comment: Try updating your NTFS driver.  e.g. 
http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/

Comment: @samiam: I just updated NTFS driver. Evince still doesn't have permission to create new folders. Do I need to restart Ubuntu to make it work? (I have a lot of things going on my computer, and I will not be able to restart my OS until later).

Comment: At this point, after restart, go to http://tuxera.com/forum/ with your question if the problem persists.  Make sure the thing is correctly mounted with `-t ntfs-3g` in the arguments to mount...see http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/ for details.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is an error with the NTFS driver on this system.  I would make sure to use the most current version of the NTFS driver:

http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/

And see if the problem persists.  If it does, here is the form for the ntfs-3g driver:

http://tuxera.com/forum/

**Troubleshooting log**

OK, the back and forth in the comment section has been going on for a while, so let me formulate a real answer here, albeit a currently incomplete one.

Here is how the OP (original poster) mounted the partition:

`/dev/sda3 on /windows-d type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)`

He can run mkdir by hand to make directories, but evince isn't able to make them.  Running strace, we get this error:

`mkdir("/windows-d/academic discipline/study objects/areas/formal systems/logic/generalize to when inference is uncertain/uncertainlize deductive logic/statistics/general/Ogunnaike/new", 0777) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)`

However, he can run mkdir to make the directory, so I'm scratching my head to why it's not working.  So, I went to see what this does:

`strace mkdir '/windows-d/academic discipline/study objects/areas/formal systems/logic/generalize to when inference is uncertain/uncertainlize deductive logic/statistics/general/Ogunnaike/new' > strace.mkdir.output 2>&1`

Here's the `mkdir()` call in the `mkdir` command:

`mkdir("/windows-d/academic discipline/study objects/areas/formal systems/logic/generalize to when inference is uncertain/uncertainlize deductive logic/statistics/general/Ogunnaike/new", 0777) = 0`

It makes the same system-level call.

Right now I suspect it could be:

- selinux gives evince limited permissions (To check, `/etc/selinux/config` to see if selinux is running and read `/var/log/audit/audit.log` to see if something is amiss; however the original poster [OP] is not running selinux)
- evince runs as a different user as his 'mkdir' commands (is evince somehow SUID to run as a different user)? (nope, evince is not SUID)
- A bug in the FUSE NTFS driver (perhaps it only fails the first time we try to make a given directory?) (I am suspecting this)

I know this isn't an answer, but the comments back and forth trying to solve this have gotten too long.

At this point, I suspect a bug in the fuse NTFS driver which causes it to intermittently fail to make directories.

Comment: Thanks! The problem persists after I updated my ntfs driver and restart .